# how to find total value from adding value in html and value in dynamic form with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have problem to find total_penjualan value.
i use dynamic form here. i want add all total's value in dynamic form with biayalainlain's value. i think the problem is in var ttl2 = document.getElementById(totalid).value; how to get id in additem() to put in prosestotal()?
this is my html and javascript code:

```js
      function sum() {
        var hrg = document.getElementById('harga').value;
        var jml = document.getElementById('jumlah').value;
        var result = parseInt(hrg) * parseInt(jml);
        if (!isNaN(result)) {
         document.getElementById('total').value = result;
       }
     }



function additem() { 


    //menentukan target append
    var itemlist = document.getElementById('itemlist');

    //                membuat element
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var nama = document.createElement('td');
    var kode = document.createElement('td');
    var harga = document.createElement('td');
    var jumlah = document.createElement('td');
    var total = document.createElement('td');
    var aksi = document.createElement('td');


    //                meng append element
    itemlist.appendChild(row);
    row.appendChild(nama);
    row.appendChild(kode);
    row.appendChild(harga);
    row.appendChild(jumlah);
    row.appendChild(total);
    row.appendChild(aksi);

    //                membuat element input1
    var nama_input = document.createElement('input');
    /*nama_input.setAttribute('id', 'nama');*/
    nama_input.setAttribute('name', 'nama_input[]');
    nama_input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

    var kode_input = document.createElement('input');
    /* kode_input.setAttribute('id', 'kode1');*/
    kode_input.setAttribute('name', 'kode_input[]');
    kode_input.setAttribute('readonly', '');
    kode_input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

    var harga_input = document.createElement('input');
    harga_input.setAttribute('type', 'number');
    harga_input.setAttribute('name', 'harga_input[]');
    harga_input.setAttribute('class', 'harga form-control');
    /*harga_input.setAttribute('onkeyup', 'sum();');*/
    

    var jumlah_input = document.createElement('input');
    jumlah_input.setAttribute('type', 'number');
    jumlah_input.setAttribute('name', 'jumlah_input[]');
    jumlah_input.setAttribute('class', 'jumlah form-control');
    jumlah_input.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
    /*jumlah_input.setAttribute('onkeyup', 'sum();');*/
    

    var total_input = document.createElement('input');
    total_input.setAttribute('name', 'total_input[]');
    total_input.setAttribute('class', 'total form-control');
    total_input.setAttribute('readonly', '');

    var hapus = document.createElement('span');

    //                meng append element input
    nama.appendChild(nama_input);
    kode.appendChild(kode_input);
    harga.appendChild(harga_input);
    jumlah.appendChild(jumlah_input);
    total.appendChild(total_input);
    aksi.appendChild(hapus);

    hapus.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-small btn-default"><b>Hapus</b></button>';
    //                membuat aksi delete element
    hapus.onclick = function () {
      row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
    };
  
    var namaid = 'nama' + (Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000));
    var kodeid = 'kode' + (Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000));
    var hargaid = 'harga' + (Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000));
    var jumlahid = 'jumlah' + (Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000));
    var totalid = 'total' + (Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000));
    nama_input.setAttribute('id', namaid);
    kode_input.setAttribute('id', kodeid);
    harga_input.setAttribute('id', hargaid);

    jumlah_input.setAttribute('id', jumlahid);
    total_input.setAttribute('id', totalid); 

    $(jumlah_input).on('keyup',function(){

      sum(hargaid,jumlahid,totalid)
    })
    $(harga_input).on('keyup',function(){

      sum(hargaid,jumlahid,totalid)
    })
    $(total_input).on('keyup',function(){

      prosestotal(totalid,total,biayalain)
    })
    
    function sum(hargaid,jumlahid,totalid) {
      var hrg = document.getElementById(hargaid).value;
      var jml = document.getElementById(jumlahid).value;
      var result = parseInt(hrg) * parseInt(jml);
      if (!isNaN(result)) {
       document.getElementById(totalid).value = result;
     }
   }

   $("#" + namaid).autocomplete({
    source: "get_barang.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $("#" + kodeid).val(ui.item.kode);
      $("#" + hargaid).val(ui.item.harga);
    }
  });

 }

 function prosestotal(){
  var ttl = document.getElementById('total').value;
  var ttl2 = document.getElementById(totalid).value;
  var biayalain = document.getElementById('biayalain').value;
  var hsl = parseInt(ttl) + parseInt(ttl2) + parseInt(biayalain);
  if (!isNaN(hsl)) {
    document.getElementById('total_penjualan').value = hsl;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-condensed" style="margin-left: 10px;">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th width="100px">Nama</th>
                  <th width="100px">Kode</th>
                  <th width="100px">Harga</th>
                  <th width="100px">Jumlah</th>
                  <th width="100px">Total</th>
                  <th width="80px"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody id='itemlist' >
                <tr>
                  <td><input id='nama' name='nama_input[]' class='form-control' /></td>
                  <td><input id='kode' readonly name='kode_input[]' class='form-control' /></td>
                  <td><input type="number" id='harga' name='harga_input[]' class='form-control' onkeyup="sum();" /></td>
                  <td><input type="number" id='jumlah' autocomplete="off" name='jumlah_input[]' class='form-control' onkeyup="sum();" /></td>
                  <td><input id='total' name='total_input[]' class='form-control' value="" onkeyup="prosestotal();" /></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>

              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                  <button type="button" id="tambah" class="btn btn-default">
                    <b>Tambah</b>
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

            <!-- Baris biaya lain-lain -->
            <div style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 15px;" class="col-lg-10">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <label class="col-sm-6 control-label"><b>Biaya Lain-lain :</b></label>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <input id="biayalain" type="number" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="biaya_lainlain" value="" onkeyup="prosestotal();">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- baris biaya dan lain-lain end -->

            <div style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 15px;" class="col-lg-10">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <label class="col-sm-6 control-label"><b>Total Penjualan :</b></label>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <input id="total_penjualan" type="number" readonly autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="total_penjualan" value="" onkeyup="prosestotal();">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: JavaScript is not really good in doing Math calculations. Just try to add 0.1 + 0.2 in the console. That's why you need to consider using some library or do the calculations on server side. Suggestion: http://numeraljs.com

Comment: BTW, your code looks really messy. Please clean it up and create JSFiddle.

Comment: @TomePejoski i have clean up my code with JSfiddle.. can you help me to define totalid in prosestotal()? how get totalid in additem() to put in prosestotal()?

Comment: Where is the JSFiddle link?

Comment: @TomePejoski this JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/cgxq8ffL/